# Finding the key matrix of a 2x2 Hill Cipher

Tags: matrices, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, cryptography

I'm trying to find the Hill Cipher key from the following given info:

(1,3)^T is encrypted as (-9, -2)^T, and (7, 2)^T is encrypted as (-2, 9)^T.

However I don't seem to end up with the correct answer as the encryption is invalid when I try to use the key. Below is my solution, did I make a mistake somewhere?

So

$$\begin{bmatrix} a & b\\ c & d\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1\\3 \end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}-9\\-2 \end{bmatrix}$$

and

$$\begin{bmatrix} a & b\\ c & d\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}7\\2 \end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}-2\\9 \end{bmatrix}$$

or in one matrix notation:

$$\begin{bmatrix} a & b\\ c & d\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 7\\ 3 & 2\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} -9 & -2\\ -2 & 9\end{bmatrix}$$

which allows us to find the encryption matrix by

$$\begin{bmatrix} a & b\\ c & d\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} -9 & -2\\ -2 & 9\end{bmatrix} {\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 7\\ 3 & 2\end{bmatrix}}^{-1}$$

The determinant of $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 7\\ 3 & 2\end{bmatrix}$ is $1\cdot 2 - 3\cdot 7 = 7 \pmod{26}$, so the inverse exists and equals

$$\begin{bmatrix} 2 & -7\\ -3 & 1\end{bmatrix}$$

This allows us to compute the encryption matrix

$$\begin{bmatrix} a & b\\ c & d\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} -9 & -2\\ -2 & 9\end{bmatrix} {\begin{bmatrix} 2 & -7\\ -3 & 1\end{bmatrix}}$$

$$
\begin{bmatrix} 
-9*2+-2*-3=14 & -9*-7+-2*1=9\\ 
-2*2+9*-3=21 & -2*-7+9*1=23\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix} 14 & 9\\ 21 & 23\end{bmatrix}
$$

Then $$\begin{bmatrix} 14 & 9\\ 21 & 23\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1\\3 \end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}15\\12 \end{bmatrix}$$ which does not match the given info as it should have been equal to

$$\begin{bmatrix}-9\\-2 \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Your inverse appears to be incorrect:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}1&7\\3&2\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}2&-7\\-3&1\end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}7&0\\0&7\end{bmatrix}\ .
$$
It looks to me like you've forgotten to divide the adjugate by the determinant.  If you divide your answer $\ \begin{bmatrix}15\\12\end{bmatrix}\ $ by $\ 7\pmod{26}\ $ you get the result you say you should have got.

Comment: @lonzaleggiera Could you maybe make an answer and explain in more detail? I'm still not getting the right key. When I divide my inverse by the determinant I get $$\begin{bmatrix} 2/7 & -1\\ -3/7 & 1/7\end{bmatrix}$$, and when I multiply this by the message matrix I get $$\begin{bmatrix} -12/7 & 61/7\\ -31/7 & 23/7\end{bmatrix}$$, did I make a mistake again? When I multiply this by $$\begin{bmatrix} 1\\ 3\end{bmatrix}$$ I'm getting a completely wrong answer. I also don't understand how dividing $$\begin{bmatrix} 15\\ 12\end{bmatrix}$$ by 7 equals $$\begin{bmatrix} -9\\ -2\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: You haven't really made a mistake, just forgot that you're working mod 26:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
-\frac{12}{7}&\frac{61}{7}\\
-\frac{31}{7}&\frac{23}{7}
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1\\3\end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}\frac{171}{7}\\ \frac{38}{7}\end{bmatrix}
$$
But $\ \frac{171}{7}\equiv\frac{15}{7}\equiv-9\pmod{26}\ $ and $\ \frac{38}{7} \equiv$$\frac{12}{7}\equiv$$-2\pmod{26}\ $.

Comment: @lonzaleggiera Could you please explain to me how you go from 15/7 to -9 (mod 26)?

Comment: Just trial and error with adding/subtracting mod 26?

Comment: My apologies. I had assumed you were sufficiently familiar with modular arithmetic to understand the explanation. For any odd integer $\ n\ $ not divisible by $13$ there will always be one of the integers $\ 1,3,\dots,25\ $ which is congruent to $\ \frac{1}{n}\pmod{26}\ $. When $\ n=7\ $ this turns out to be $15$—that is $\ 7\cdot15\equiv1 \pmod{26}\ $, so $\ \frac{1}{7} \equiv15\pmod{26}\ $, and $\ \frac{15}{7}\equiv$$ 15\cdot15\equiv$$ 9\cdot25$$\equiv-9\pmod{26}\ $.

Answer (score 1):

I fully agree with

$$\begin{bmatrix} a & b\\ c & d\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} -9 & -2\\ -2 & 9\end{bmatrix} {\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 7\\ 3 & 2\end{bmatrix}}^{-1}$$
and indeed the determinant of the right hand side matrix equals $$2- 21 \pmod{26} = -19 = 7 \pmod{26}$$ which is relatively prime to $26$ so has an inverse.

The general formula for an 2-by-2 inverse is:

$$A^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}a & b\\c & d\end{bmatrix}^{-1} = \frac{1}{\det A}
\begin{bmatrix}d &-b\\-c & a\end{bmatrix}$$ so your inverse is wrong and all entries need to be multiplies by the invesre (modulo $26$) of the determinant $7$.

This inverse can be found by applying the extended Euclidean algorithm to $7$ and $26$ and we get the Bézout identity

$$1 = -11 \cdot 7 + 3\cdot 26$$

from which it follows that $$-11 \cdot 7 = 1 \pmod{26}$$

so that the inverse of $7$ is $-11 \equiv 15$.

So we multiply all elements of $$\begin{bmatrix} 2 & -7\\ -3 & 1\end{bmatrix}$$ by $15$ to get the inverse matrix we're looking for (of course all modulo $26$)

and we get $$\begin{bmatrix} 4 & 18\\ 7 & 15\end{bmatrix}$$

and now you can do the multiplication from the first equation modulo 26:

$$\begin{bmatrix} -9 & -2\\ -2 & 9\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 4 & 18\\ 7 & 15\end{bmatrix}$$ to find the encryption matrix $E$. I leave that final bit to you.

takeaway: division is multiplying by the inverse. The inverse is found by the extended Euclidean algorithm. For $n=26$ you could also find the table of inverses once (program or trial and error) and use them all the time.